# Thrifty rental car pickup in Vienna

Tags: car-rentals, austria, vienna

I booked a rental car online from Thrifty, to be picked up at **VIENNA MAIN RAILWAY STATION, AM HAUPTBAHNHOF 1** (at least that's what the reservation voucher states).

The problem is: Thrifty does not list any pickup-location at this spot in their [full list of locations](https://www.thrifty.com/local_sites_index.aspx) (only Vienna Airport is listed), and the [train station's official home page](http://hauptbahnhofcity.wien/shopping/) states that only the Avis, Europcar, Hertz, and Sixt companies operate local stores there.

Where do I have to go to pick up my car?

Comment: Call Thrifty.  Isn't this a question for them, rather than the internet?

Comment: I guess you could say that about many questions on this platform ;) The intention was to check if someone already had the same problem and want to share their answer publicly, if not I'll need to get in contact with Thrifty directly, of course.

Comment: there is certainly a gray area where some questions could be asked of a company or on this site.  However, this seems like information that should be provided directly by the company as part of your business with them.  And you need a definitive answer, which can only come from them in my opinion.  I would not be confident going to pick up a car base on an answer from a Q&A site in the absence of clear information from the company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that, since Thrifty is part of the Hertz company somehow, cars are to be picked up at the Hertz counter at the Vienna train station.